# Django Creating a new post, but it belongs to none

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

Creating a new checklist, the checklist get created but I have to go inn admin panel to set what task it belongs to. The task is a foreignkey in the checklist.

views.py

```
def project_detail(request, slug):
    '''
    Detailed view of given project
    '''
    context = {}
    project     = get_object_or_404(Project, slug=slug)
    tasks       = Task.objects.filter(task_completed=False, project=project)

    context.update({'project': project})
    checklist_form  = ChecklistForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == "POST":
        # Create new Checklist
        if 'save_new_checklist' in request.POST:
            if checklist_form.is_valid():
                print("\n\n New checklist form is valid")
                author = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
                new_checklist = checklist_form.save(commit=False)
                new_checklist.user = author
                new_checklist.tasks = tasks
                new_checklist.save()

                return redirect('project_detail', slug=slug)


    context.update({
        'tasks': tasks,
        'checklist_form': checklist_form,
        'title': tasks
    })

    return render(request, 'projects/tasks.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=55, null=True, blank=True)
    slug            = models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True, blank=True)
    task_completed  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    description     = models.TextField(default="Task description")
    date            = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    due_date        = models.DateTimeField()

    project         = models.ForeignKey(Project, blank=True, null=True, related_name='task', on_delete=CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Task, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Checklist(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    slug            = models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True, blank=True)
    date            = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    due_date        = models.DateTimeField()
    check_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    description     = models.TextField(default="Checklist description")

    task            = models.ForeignKey(Task, blank=True, null=True, related_name='checklist', on_delete=CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Checklist, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('task_detail', kwargs={
            'slug':self.slug
        })

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('projects/', teams, name='teams'),
    path('projects/project/<slug>/', projects, name='projects'),
    path('projects/tasks/<slug>/', project_detail, name='project_detail'),
    path('projects/checklist/<slug>/', task_detail, name='task_detail'),
]
```

The form is valid, no errors, the new checklist is created, only that it should be automatically belong to the given task. And it does not, have to go admin panel and choose what task it belongs to.

Comment: `new_checklist.tasks = tasks`, in this line what is `new_checklist.tasks`? That is not the same as your `Checklist.task` foreign key

Comment: I have tried  new_checklist.tasks = Checklist.task  And some other combinations, still not getting the right foreignkey @BrianDestura